# How to print last n lines of a dstream in spark streaming?

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

Spark streaming dstream print() displays first 10 lines like 
`val fileDstream = ssc.textFileStream("hdfs://localhost:9000/abc.txt")`
`fileDstream.print()`
Is there are way to get last `n` lines considering that text file is large in size and unsorted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this, you could simplify to:

```
fileDstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      rdd.collect().last
    }
```

However, this has the problem of collecting all data to the driver.

Is your data sorted? If so, you could reverse the sort and take the first. Alternatively, a hackey implementation might involve a mapPartitionsWithIndex that returns an empty iterator for all partitions except for the last. For the last partition, you would filter all elements except for the last element in your iterator. This should leave one element, which is your last element.

OR you can also try with

```
fileDstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.top(10)(reverseOrdering)
}
```

Comment: @Prabhat : please make the answer as correct if it works for you